# What are the limitations of the limit product rule?

Tags: limits

Consider the limit product rule:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} (f(x)⋅g(x))=[\lim _{x\rightarrow c} f(x)]⋅[\lim_{x\rightarrow c} g(x)]$$

Now consider, for the sake of the argument, $f(x) = x, g(x) = (e/x)$

Clearly, the limit is e. However, by the product it would be impossible to figure out. Does this mean that the product rule is only valid when the components don't have a limit of 0 or infinity? Will it always work for other cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually such a rule would be stated:

"If $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)$ both exist, then $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to c} f(x) \lim_{x \to c} g(x)$"

So in your supplied example, one of the limits does not exist and the rule would not apply.  For that case you would examine $fg$ instead of trying to use algebra of limits.

Comment: Actually a slight generalization is used in practice. Let $\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)$ exist and be non-zero. Then $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x)$ exists (or does not exist) if $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ exists (or does not exist). Thus the behavior of $f(x)g(x)$ is similar to that of $f(x)$ as far existence of limit is concerned.